# Operator acting on bras

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, notation, linear-algebra

I need some help. Suppose, $\hat{\textbf{A}}$ and $\hat{\textbf{B}}$ are operators and $|\psi\rangle$ is any state, so that
$$ \hat{\textbf{A}}|\psi\rangle=a|\psi\rangle. $$

And I wonder if this operation is correct
$$ \langle \psi| \hat{\textbf{A}}^\dagger = \langle \psi|a^*.$$

And, can I get into bra with my operator like
$$ \hat{\textbf{A}} \langle \psi|  = \langle \psi|a^*.$$
or
$$  \langle \hat{\textbf{A}}\psi|  = \langle \psi|a^*.$$

Can somebody explain? I'm so confused about acting operators on bra...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the phrasing of the question might be a bit misleading, since you are obviously talking not about *any* state, but about *any eigenstate of $\mathbf{\hat{A}}$*, since it satisfies the property
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{\hat{A}}|\psi\rangle = a|\psi\rangle.
\end{equation}
Note, btw, that $\mathbf{\hat{A}}$ is not necessarily Hermitian (otherwise $a$ would be real, and it woudln't make much sense to talk about $a^*$.)

Let us note that the following are equivalent notations (they mean the same thing):
\begin{equation}
\langle\varphi|\mathbf{\hat{A}}|\psi\rangle = \langle\varphi|\mathbf{\hat{A}}\psi\rangle.
\end{equation}

The complex conjugation in the bra-ket notation is expressed as:
\begin{equation}
\langle\varphi|\psi\rangle^* = \langle\psi|\varphi\rangle.
\end{equation}

Now, for *any* states $|\varphi\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle$ we have
\begin{equation}
\langle\varphi|\mathbf{\hat{A}}|\psi\rangle^* = 
\langle\varphi|\mathbf{\hat{A}}\psi\rangle^* =
\langle \mathbf{\hat{A}}\psi|\varphi\rangle = 
\langle\psi|\mathbf{\hat{A}}^\dagger\varphi\rangle =
\langle\psi|\mathbf{\hat{A}}^\dagger|\varphi\rangle.
\end{equation}
The equality $\langle \mathbf{\hat{A}}\psi|\varphi\rangle = 
\langle\psi|\mathbf{\hat{A}}^\dagger\varphi\rangle$ is actually the definition of the Hermitian adjoint for operator $\mathbf{\hat{A}}$.

Now, if $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $\mathbf{\hat{A}}$, then for *any* $|\varphi\rangle$ we have 
\begin{equation}
\langle\psi|\mathbf{\hat{A}}^\dagger|\varphi\rangle =
\langle\varphi|\mathbf{\hat{A}}|\psi\rangle^* =
\left(\langle\varphi|\psi\rangle a\right)^* = 
a^*\langle\psi|\varphi\rangle.
\end{equation}
Since $|\varphi\rangle$ is an arbitrary state, this means that 
\begin{equation}
\langle\psi|\mathbf{\hat{A}}^\dagger =
a^*\langle\psi| = \langle\psi|a^*.
\end{equation}

The remaining point in your question is the expression
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{\hat{A}}\langle\psi| = \langle\psi|a^*.
\end{equation}
This is incorrect notation: the opertaor always acts from the side of $|$, not from the side of the angular bracket.

Comment: does the sign * mean complex conjugation in equation
$\langle \varphi |\hat{\textbf{A}}|\psi \rangle* $?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I corrected it.

Comment: and shouldn't it be like $\langle \varphi|\psi\rangle ^* = \langle\psi|\varphi\rangle$?

Comment: This is also correct.

Comment: Thank tou very much!

Comment: My homework is to calculate the expected value of $[\hat{\textbf{A}}, \hat{\textbf{B}}]$. When I calculate, there is a term:
$$ \langle \phi| \hat{\textbf{A}} \hat{\textbf{B}} | \phi \rangle . $$ 

And I have problem, because I know only that
$$ \langle \phi| \hat{\textbf{A}}^\dagger = \langle \phi|a^*.$$

With assumption that $\hat{\textbf{A}}$ is self-adjointed it's easy. But can I calculate it without this assumption?

Comment: At the first glance it doesn't seem like a well posed problem... Look however for an indication that the operator is Hermitian - e.g., that $\mathbf{\hat{A}}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{B}}$ correspond to physical quantities.